# Simpler way to max() two Ordered objects

Tags: scala

Given two Ordered vals, I can find maximum using following code:

```
abstract class C extends Ordered[C] ()

val v1: C = ???
val v2: C = ???

val max = implicitly[Ordering[C]].max(v1, v2)
```

Can it be done simpler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you `import Ordering._`, you get `v1 max v2` (or `v1.max(v2)`, as you might prefer). Also `v1 < v2`, etc

Comment: Correction: `import Ordering._`

Comment: Ok, let met fix the answer then. Thx.

Comment: In Scala 2.12 I had to use `import Ordering.Implicits._`

Comment: Is there a way to be more clever, and do a `minBy`? Use case in point, comparing elements of an `IndexedSeq` given indices `i` and `j`. Any chum can do `items(i) min items(j)`, but where's the fun in that?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it is much simpler (and it may actually suit better when you have more than 2 elements that you want to find their max) but you can do:

```
val max = List(v1, v2).max
```

as that max method on collection takes an implicit `Ordering`

Comment: I think it's an overkill to create a `List` in this case. Would OP need arbitrary amount of objects to compare, he would state so.

Answer (score 0):

> [Write clearly -- don't be too clever. Say what you mean, simply and
>   directly.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Elements_of_Programming_Style#Lessons)

```
val max = if (v1 > v2) v1 else v2
```